# Maven lifecycle wrong order

Tags: java, maven, maven-lifecycle

I deploy my application during the `package` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>gf-redeploy</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>redeploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And run some integration-tests in the `integration-test` phase

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However when I look into my console, the JMeter test is executed before the `redeploy`. How is that possible? Did I miss something?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem: I have a multi module project and placed the jmeter test into the right module. See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503773/maven-phase-order-with-mulit-module-project

Comment: The [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) show the phase order. Integration tests come before deploy/redeploy because those tests must happen before deploying. If you're testing the deployment, you're only testing, not integration-testing.